# Jacobi Theta Function on the Unit Circle - Is there a Limit in the Distribution Sense?

Tags: special-functions, theta-functions

The third Jacobi theta function

$$\theta_{3}\left(z,q\right)=1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}}\cos\left(2\pi n z\right)$$

appears in the study of path integrals in QM. Specifically in the problem of a particle on a ring (see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297278/the-position-representation-matrix-elements-of-the-propagator-for-a-particle-in)). In that case it happens that $\left|q\right|=1$, rendering the function undefined. However, I am expecting a limit to exist for $\left|q\right|\uparrow1$ at least in the distribution sense. For instance (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180506/dirac-distribution)), if $q=1$

$$\theta_{3}\left(z,q\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(z-n\right)$$

Can this result be generalized for any $q$ on the unit circle? Will we also get a comb of deltas? Maybe other well-known distributions? My goal is to get a more descriptive expression that can be visualized, if possible, including an understanding of what happens when I change $z,q$. Any directions/relevant references would be of help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have to consider a limit $|q|\to1$ in any form (unless it is explicitly needed) since, in the sense of distributions, the sum is well-defined even if $|q|=1$. As a starting point, consider the case of $q$ being a root of unity.

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks! I would want to argue it would be a sum of shifted combs, depending on the periodicity of the power $e^{2\pi i\frac{a}{b}}$. Not sure however.

Comment: In one sense, /Farey-sequence-distributed/ is a sum of shifted and scaled combs. Depending on what features of the limit you need looking at the Hardy-Ramanujan circle method and/or quantum modular forms might be relevant. https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/qmf/fulltext.pdf

Comment: For $q$ not a root of unity then $\sum_n e^{2i\pi n x} q^{n^2}$ converges to a $1$-periodic distribution and it doesn't simplify. For $q$ a $m$-th root of unity it is $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} q^{k^2}\sum_n e^{2i\pi (nm+k) x} =\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} q^{k^2}  e^{2i\pi k x} \sum_l  \delta(mx-l)= \frac1m \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} q^{k^2}   \sum_l  e^{2i\pi k l/m} \delta(x-l/m)$ @Cameron

Comment: The limit possibly exists as analytic functional, not necessarily a distribution. There's an old paper by Gianfranco Cimmino which could be of some help in this cases.

Comment: @reuns sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: @DanieleTampieri which paper are you referring to?

Comment: @Cameron: Gianfanco Cimmino, "Sulla totalita delle funzioni che in un dato campo verificano una equazione differenziale lineare omogenea", (Italian) Atti Accad. Sci. Ist. Bologna, Cl. Sci. Fis., Ann. 248, Rend., XI. Ser. 7, No. 1, 86-94 (1960), [MR0133580](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0133580), [Zbl 0115.08801](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0115.08801). The result was later generalized to the boundary values on an hypersurface of solutions of an elliptic system with analytic coefficients by Lions and Magenes in their monograph on boundary value problems.

Comment: @Cameron the paper is quite difficult to obtain, but there's a copy included in Cimmino's selecta. Let me know if you need a copy of it: it is in italian but it is an "easy read".

Comment: @Cameron I’ll send you a scan this evening, when I’ll be in my home office.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Amazing thank you! :)

Comment: @reuns Your comment was helpful in a paper I am writing, can I acknowledge your help? Thank you! Cameron