# Infinite sum over $e^{i \frac{\pi (n-x)^2}{a}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, dirac-delta, exponential-sum

I would like to evaluate the infinite sum
$$\sum_n \exp \left(  \frac{i\pi}{a} (n-x)^2\right)$$
where $x,a\in \mathbb R$.

For certain values of $a$ it becomes a Delta comb of various frequencies, however I can't figure out a general expression

Comment: Looks like the theta function. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function)

Comment: @KentaS it would be if $Im(a)>0$ but I am interested in the case that $Im(a)=0$

Comment: A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3439816) is still unanswered.